# calling new website in java jsp

Tags: java, jsp, derby

I am coding a login authorization system. It is working with a database and it is checks the correct username and password with the database. After that, the program opens a new website with a login button like

> "Welcome to the system"

I have to create a register page as well. I added this button to index, but when I click the button, the program gives an error like "wrong password". How can I overcome that? When I press the register button it should take the username and password and insert them into the database.

Here  is the code cevap.jsp

```
enter code here
<%-- 
Document   : cevap
Created on : 17.Ara.2016, 14:26:30
Author     : BURAK NURÇİÇEK
--%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>ONLINE ACTIVTY TICKET SYSTEM</h1>
<jsp:useBean id="bean" scope="session" class="veri.kisi" />
<jsp:setProperty name="bean" property="username"/>    
<jsp:setProperty name="bean" property="password" />


<% if(bean.checkPassword()) {
out.println("Welcome To The  System"); 
} else{
out.println("Wrong Password");
}
%>

</body>
</html>
```

This is index.html

```
enter code here
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
<head>
<title>ONLINE TICKET MANAGER ACTIVTY SYSTEM</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<div>BUY YOUR TICKETS ONLINE</div><br/>
<form action="cevap.jsp">
Username:
<input type="text" name="username" value="" />
Password:
<input type="password" name="password" value="" />
<input type="submit" value=Login />
<input type="submit" value="Register" />

</form>
</body>
</html>*
```

This is databaselayer class

```
enter code here
/*
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project         
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package veri;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

/**
*
* @author BURAK NURÇİÇEK
*/
public class DatabaseLayer {

private Connection con;
String url="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/users";
String root="users";
String password="123";
public Connection connect() {
try {
                          Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();
                con=DriverManager.getConnection(url, root, password);
               System.out.println("Connected");
   } catch(Exception e) {
       System.out.println("Not Connected");
   }
    return con;
}

 public boolean checkUser(String username,String password) {
 if(con==null) {
    System.out.println("no connection");
    connect();
}
try {
       Statement state=con.createStatement(); 
       ResultSet rs= state.executeQuery("select password from users where username='"+username+"'");
       rs.next();
       return password.equals(rs.getString(1));


  }catch(Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
return false;
 }

 }
```

This is `kisi` class (which means person in English).

```
enter code here
/*
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project 
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package veri;

/**
*
* @author BURAK NURÇİÇEK
*/
public class kisi {
String username;
String password;

   public static void main(String args[]) {

  }
 public boolean checkPassword() {
 DatabaseLayer layer=new DatabaseLayer();
 return  layer.checkUser(username,password);

 }

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}



}
```

Comment: did you need to get cashed  username and password ?

Comment: Fixed up some grammar to clarify question

Comment: I changed the tag to Derby, not mysql, because the author is using Derby Database. The title should be improved.

Comment: What, precisely, is the question? Are you asking how to insert a new row into your table?